# 'kapt.generateStubs' is not used by the 'kotlin-kapt' plugin

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, annotations, kotlin

I recently updated from Android Studio 2.3 to 3.0, and kotlin `1.1.4` to `1.1.51`.

Now I'm seeing this message in my gradle console:

> 'kapt.generateStubs' is not used by the 'kotlin-kapt' plugin

I have this in my `build.gradle` to get my project working with some libraries using annotation processing:

> kapt { generateStubs = true }

Is the `generateStubs` line no longer needed and is it safe to remove? Or is there another action I should take to remove the warning message above?

Comment: May be relevant: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kapt-generatestubs/3736/2

Answer (score 71, accepted):

It is completely safe to remove `kapt { generateStubs = true }`. It was originally used by `kapt1`, which is deprecated now.

Some docs about kapt:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html

Answer (score 10):

You should apply the kotlin-kapt plugin in your build.gradle file and remove the generateStubs = true

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```