# Inject provider of ViewModelProvider.Factory into esspresso test

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, android-espresso, android-viewmodel

I have custom implementation of `ViewModel.Factory` which is provided by lambda injected by `Dagger2`

```
interface ViewModelFactoryComponent {
    val factoryProvider: (Bundle?) -> ViewModelProvider.Factory
}
```

Dagger implementation looks like below:

```
@Module
class ViewModelModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun bindViewModelFactory(creators: Map<Class<out ViewModel>, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<(Bundle?) -> ViewModel>>): (Bundle?) -> ViewModelProvider.Factory {
        return { ViewModelFactory(creators, it) }
    }
}

@Singleton
@Component(modules = [ ApplicationModule::class, ViewModelModule::class])
interface ApplicationComponent : ViewModelFactoryComponent
```

In application everything works like a charm but problem appeared when I've tried to configure `Espresso` test. Here's dagger test component configuration:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [ApplicationModule::class, ViewModelModule::class])
interface TestComponent : ApplicationComponent
```

Now what is the problem - test component implementation generated by dagger generate function like this

```
 @Override
  public Function1<Bundle, ViewModelProvider$Factory> getFactoryProvider() {
    return bindViewModelFactoryProvider.get();
  }
```

which generate compilation error, instead like in real app:

```
  @Override
  public Function1<Bundle, ViewModelProvider.Factory> getFactoryProvider() {
    return bindViewModelFactoryProvider.get();
  }
```

First I thought it's a case of `ViewModelProvider.Factory` visibility, but all `build.gradle` modification didn't help. I've met with total lack of idea so I will be greatfull for at least some suggestions.

**UPDATE**
I have created empty project to reproduce this error and it suppose to be completly repeatable.

File in `main` directory:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [ViewModelModule::class])
interface ApplicationComponent : ViewModelFactoryComponent

@Module
class ViewModelModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun bindViewModelFactory(): () -> ViewModelProvider.Factory {
        return { ViewModelFactory() }
    }
}

interface ViewModelFactoryComponent {
    val factoryProvider: () -> ViewModelProvider.Factory
}

class ViewModelFactory @Inject constructor() : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return modelClass.newInstance()
    }
}

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()
```

File in `androidTest` directory:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [ViewModelModule::class])
interface TestComponent : ApplicationComponent

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class TestCase {
    @get:Rule
    val activityTestRule = ActivityTestRule(MainActivity::class.java, false, false)

    @Test
    fun appLaunchesSuccessfully() {
        ActivityScenario.launch(MainActivity::class.java)
    }
}
```

And this are all dependencies:

```
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.21'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.21'
    kaptAndroidTest 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.21'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.1'
```

Application is build without any problem but when I try to launch `appLaunchesSuccessfully()` test, compile error from reason above, appear.

**Edit**
So, I figured out that without `kaptAndroidTest 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.21'` test project can be build successfully.
The bad new is that without it dagger component class won't generate.

Comment: it's difficult to tell for certain, because that "compile error" had been omitted.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I will add stacktrace, but there is nothing interested there. Just generated funcrtion `public Function1<Bundle, ViewModelProvider$Factory> getFactoryProvider()` does not compile because of '$'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1454 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/KT-27936 there is only a temporary solution under first link

Answer (score 0):

think you need this plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

with these `dependencies`:

```
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.21"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.21"
```

and enable option `generateStubs`:

```
kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
```

there are lots of [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dagger-2+kotlin) ...also see the [user's guide](https://google.github.io/dagger/users-guide).

`kaptAndroidTest` might be useless.

Comment: about `generateStubs = true` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47044955/kapt-generatestubs-is-not-used-by-the-kotlin-kapt-plugin